# Need to export a scan profile to provide report on what Fortify is scanning for?

Tags: fortify

Looking for the method to export the scan profile I have established to scan our code.  How do you export a scan profile to show what the profile is scanning for?

Comment: I searched the Fortify KnowledgeBase for the term "scan profile" and found nothing. Would you kindly clarify what you mean by scan profile?